# Recursively search files with filter on full path in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, recursion

I can use `dir /s /b *.Tests.*.dll` to recursively find all files that match that pattern, but I need to also find them only if they are in `\bin\Debug\` instead of `\obj\Debug\` or `\bin\Release`.

So I tried this command:

```
dir /s /b Tests\Unit\*\Debug\bin\*.Tests.*.dll
```

But it fails with `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`

I couldn't find any previous SO question that addresses this problem but if one exists please point it to me.

Is there any way to achieve the desired result (apply filter on entire path)? My intent is to use the list to run NUnit on each unit test assembly in my project under jenkins using this command from [Use NUnit Console Runner to run all tests under a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34395554/use-nunit-console-runner-to-run-all-tests-under-a-folder)

```
for /f %%f in ('dir .\test\ /b /s *.Test.dll') do nunit-console /nologo /noshadow /framework:net-4.0 /xml:.\test\TestResults.xml "%%f"
```

On linux I would have used `ls -r ... | grep ... | xargs ...` and I'm trying to achieve something similar here.

I only need to apply this additional filter on the parent folders as well. If it's not possible I'll have to use PowerShell.

Comment: I don't think `dir` works with wildcard(`*`), except the filename or file extension

Comment: Also, in `*.Tests.*.dll`, do you mean `*.Tests. *.dll`? Space makes a big difference. The first one search can match files like: a.Test.b.dll(**one file!**), the second matches. a.tests, b.dll

Comment: Uhmm. By the way, I don't understand what folders and files does your script wants to match. The word `only` in the first sentence confused me.

Comment: I've written `*.Tests.*.dll`. Where do you see the space?

Comment: oh welp. I was sleepy... misread it, sorry :(

Comment: Uhm.. Can you please add the folder/file structure and the expected result?

Comment: Never mind, I found a solution which I'll post.

Answer (score 1):

```
FOR /d %%a IN ("%sourcedir1%\*") DO DIR /s /b "%%~a\%sourcedir2%\*.exe" 2>nul
```

where `sourcedir1` is the part of the required path before the `\*\` and `sourcedir2` the part after.

simply assign each dirname in turn to `%%a` and use that as the start point for the second `dir`

Answer (score 0):

I found [DOS batch script with for loop and pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6026773/dos-batch-script-with-for-loop-and-pipe), and using the idea there I constructed this command:

```
for /f %f in ('dir /s /b Tests\Unit ^| findstr \\bin\\Debug\\.*\.Tests\..*\.dll$"') do echo %f
```

No I only need to replace `%f` with `%%f` for batch files, and I can replace `echo %f` with the command to run nunit.

Comment: In the first sentence, do you mean `Windows batch script` instead of `DOS batch script`? `DOS` is an old operating system. `CMD` is your command prompt.

Comment: I mean a windows batch script.